# How to have vpn connection always on in iOS

Tags: ios7, vpn, connectivity

I have a client requirement and he wants his VPN connection to be always on even when the device goes to sleep or switched off and on.I would like to know if there is a way to keep VPN always active.(no jailbreak and no private api's).

Answer (score 5):

VPN on demand is a clever Apple feature that enables a VPN connection to be initiated without needing to go into settings or even leave the application you want to use. However please note that iOS only supports VPN On Demand for networks that use certificated-based authentication (Rathe than username&Password authentication). You specify which domains require a VPN connection by using a configuration profile
The VPN connection is made whenever the device tries to connect to certain domains. Specific apps don't need to do anything; as soon as they try to access such a server the VPN connection is initiated.

Read [this article](http://www.derman.com/blogs/Setting-Up-iOS-OnDemand-VPN) for information about how to use the Configuration Utility to create a configuration profile that sets up VPN On Demand.
The following Article could also be helpful:
http://jelockwood.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-do-vpn-on-demand-for-ios-at-zero.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll look forward to it ;and i would also like to be in contact with you.@RoseAb